# How to keep all matching rows(with criteria), and deleted all others including empty rows in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the vba i use, but it can contains only 2 criteria, 
I need to apply 3 or 4 criteria.

```
Sub supprimer()

    Sheets("A").Select

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A")

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Agent*", Criteria2:="<>*Receive*"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End sub()
```

Thanks in advance
JL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do an `And` exclusion filter with more than 2 criteria, but this macro will accomplish what you want. It will delete all blank rows and all rows that do not contain the criteria.

```
Sub supprimer()
    Sheets("A").Select

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A")
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        Set rng = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        If rng.Text <> "" Then
            If Not InStr(1, rng.Text, "Agent") > 0 _
                    And Not InStr(1, rng.Text, "Receive") > 0 _
                    And Not InStr(1, rng.Text, "Criteria3") > 0 _
                    And Not InStr(1, rng.Text, "Criteria4") > 0 _
                    Then
                rng.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Else
            'cell is empty, delete this row
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to thank you Ross McConeghy, the macro works perfectly.